# angular routing issue on child of lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

Iam facing problem in routing  child of lazy loaded modules, it redirect on click the link but on refresh it it says abc/runtime.js

it redirects but on refresh it give this error

```
 GET http://localhost:4200/research-institutes/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

app module routing

```
           path:'',
           component:DefaultComponent,
           children: [
                 {
                   path:'research-institutes',
                   loadChildren:'../../src/app/views/research-institutes/research-institutes.module#ResearchInstitutesModule'
           }
```

]

lazy loaded module routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
       path:'',
     component:InstitutesListingComponent
   },
   {
     path:'detail',
     component:InstituteDetailComponent
   }
];

 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Does this error happens locally or on a hosted domain?

Comment: locally, however i haven't tested yet on hosted domain, because my site is hosted on apache server so before testing this error i have to first write some re write rules otherwise apache server will return page not found, that's an other issue, ill deal later for now i have to solve this issue  on local, routing should work on local server.

Comment: So we can rule out the potential config of rewrite rules ;).

Comment: Have you added RouterModule.forRoot(routes) using the default PathLocationStrategy in your app module?

Comment: its not location hash strategy related issue, i could add hash if that was the issue. its simple routing any child of lazy loaded module shows same error  either direct routing from browser url bar  or refresh page

Comment: @PZ_R, help me understand this, because it might be what I'm dealing with. So, you get a **browser** 404 (not an Angular 404, you can see in your Network tab)? But only when refreshing while the URL is pointed at a LazyLoaded child-route? In your Network tab, you see the 404 but the response body contains your index.html? If all that is true, we have the same issue. In that case, I think Angular tries to load the route (say, `/home`) and the client-side routing hasn't kicked in yet and doesn't modify the PushState of the app. So the browser throws the error. Would love to solve this.

Comment: its more than a year, if I recall correctly i guess I solved this routing issue by adding htaccess file. You can google more about redirecting  through htaccess

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration) the correct way to use lazyloading is

```
{
  path:'research-institutes',
  loadChildren: () => import('../../src/app/views/research-institutes/research-institutes.module').then(m => m.ResearchInstitutesModule)
 }
```

Comment: As this is true. This approach is not supported in Angular 7 or lower. Starting from Angular 8 this is the recommend approach. What the author uses is a valid way of loading lazy loaded modules and as well works in Angular 8.

Comment: its in angular 8, iam using angular 7

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice. I had a similar error when I was trying to set up lazy loading and this approach solved it for me so I though it could help, but I was using Angular 8